# How to print contents of list instead of type? C#

Tags: c#

There's a list variable which called 'investList'.
it has 56 rows and each rows have several columns.

i could check that via debugger,
but i had to print them on console to show my boss.

so i wrote code like

```
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var d in investList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(investList[i]);
                }
```

but the console gave me wrong answer like 'KPXDbConnection.Recommend.Model.WeeklyCombineData'

and i've tried this

```
string items = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, investList);

Console.WriteLine(items);
```

these codes gave me same answer like 'KPXDbConnection.Recommend.Model.WeeklyCombineData'

umm,,,, how can i get the contents of investList?

Comment: You need to override `ToString `method of `KPXDbConnection.Recommend.Model.WeeklyCombineData`

Comment: If you want the content to be displayed you should use the ToString() method. You are passing the entire object and not the property you want to print

Comment: FYI: This has nothing to do with the data being in a list, and is simply the default behaviour when calling `Console.WriteLine` with an instance of a class that doesn't override `ToString()`.